# Jenkins JSON Result Build Request

Tags: git, continuous-integration, jenkins

I was looking for a way to request a build request through calling a url that would return JSON so that I would be able to setup a hook with git to validate unit tests after each push to the remote repository.  I found url that looked like what I want so I tried:

```
http://www.doamin.com:8082/job/bare-bone-test/build/api/json
```

however when I try to do there in my browser I get the

> Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for
>   this address in a way that will never complete

even though it does trigger a build of that job.  Is this the correct way to request a build that will return a JSON response?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API#RemoteaccessAPI-Submittingjobs):

> ### Submitting jobs
>
> For a job with no parameters, you need merely go an
>   HTTP GET on
>
> ```
> JENKINS_URL/job/JOBNAME/build?token=TOKEN
> ```
>
> where TOKEN is set up in the job configuration.
>
> If you have parameters, you need to send JSON. Here's a snipped of
>   shell, with a few extra newlines to be more readable.
>
> ```
> json="{\"parameter\": [{\"name\": \"taskfile\", \"value\":
> \"$taskfile\"}, {\"name\": \"task\", \"value\": \"$task\"}, {\"name\":
> \"jobParameters\", \"value\": \"$jobargs\"}], \"\": \"\"}"
> url=http://hudson.basistech.net/job/benson-segmentation-training/build
> curl -X POST $url -d token=zorn --data-urlencode json="$json"
> ```

I'm not quite sure if the `TOKEN` field is really necessary. I was able to kick off a build using a simple get to the job//build URL:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/job/testjob/build
* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /job/testjob/build HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Server: Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10
< Location: http://localhost:8080/job/testjob/
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< Date: Mon, 08 Aug 2011 20:48:37 GMT
< X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 (Winstone/0.9.10)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

For a git post-commit hook, this should be enough.

#### Redirect, wtf?

The reason you're seeing the infinite redirect issue, is that the `build/api/json` URL redirects to the `build/api` endpoint (I think the handler for the `build` url tries to redirect back to the job status page by chopping off the last part of the URL). For some strange reason, `build/api` redirects back to itself. I don't think that the build supports the `api/json` suffix, but as shown above, it isn't needed.

Comment: Looks like the token parameter is only necessary when you've got simple security enabled: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Quick+and+Simple+Security

Comment: The issue is that I want to determine if the build was good in the github postback script, not just trigger the build

Comment: Would you mind updating your question to reflect that please?